# WCF Tcp Binding "The requested address is not valid in its context" Error

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

I have a WCF server using a netTcpBinding and a client. When I run them locally they work fine.

If I put the server on a Windows Server 2008 machine and try to run it, it fails unless I change the address to localhost, but no clients can connect to it.

I can run the client from the server to connect to a Windows Xp machine running the server and all is well.

Here is the server bindings:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Ricochet.Server.Controller">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://myServerIP:3315" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Ricochet.Interfaces.IServer" bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="InsecureTcp">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I created rules on the firewall to allow all traffic to the port I am using here, but no luck. Is there something else I need to do on Windows Server 2003 to get this to work?

Comment: Did you use valid IP address of your server? Is address in the list if you run ipconfig /all on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net tcp binding reqiures Network Activation Services, which is only available on Windows 2008, Vista and Windows 7. This could be part of your problem.

The other is the firewall, have you opened port 3315?