# WCF : PlatformNotSupportedException when running Server Projects

Tags: c#, wcf

I apologize in advance for being too vague, if you need any precision I will do my best to give it.

I compiled 2 different WCF "Code Project" sample apps, and I am getting the following exception whatever the one I launch, so I guess there is something misconfigured on my machine :

**EDIT**
*I Tried on a different machine (Same OS, win 7 64) and it is working fine.

I just can't figure out what configuration is wrong or missing on my computer.*

```
{"Operation is not supported on this platform."}
at System.Net.HttpListener..ctor()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at WCFService.MainForm.startWCFServer() in D:\xxx\MainForm.cs:line 77
```

Below is the code. Nothing unusual, basic WCF stuff I guess.

```
    private ServiceHost host = null;

    public void startWCFServer()
    {
            // Create the url that is needed to specify where the service should be tarted
            urlService = "net.tcp://" + "127.0.0.1" + ":8000/MyService";

            // Instruct the ServiceHost that the type that is used is a ServiceLibrary.service1
            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceLibrary.service1));
            host.Opening += new EventHandler(host_Opening);
            host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
            host.Closing += new EventHandler(host_Closing);
            host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);

            // The binding is where we can choose what transport layer we want to use. HTTP, TCP ect.
            NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None; // <- Very crucial

            // Add endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceLibrary.IService1), tcpBinding, urlService);

            // A channel to describe the service. Used with the proxy scvutil.exe tool
            ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
            metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (metadataBehavior == null)
            {
                // This is how I create the proxy object that is generated via the svcutil.exe tool
                metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                //metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8001/MyService");
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://" + "127.0.0.1" + ":8001/MyService");
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                metadataBehavior.ToString();
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
                urlMeta = metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl.ToString();
            }

            host.Open(); // <---- EXCEPTION BLOWS HERE

    }
```

**DETAILS :** 
Demo Apps are [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcf_bohansen.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/real_time_ticker.aspx) and dropping the same exception described above
It could be an UAC issue as stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/985c005f-08ba-42ab-9a72-48fb8823f7ca/) But that did not fix my issue.
OS is Windows 7 x64

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the Windows Communication Foundation HTTP/Non-HTTP Activation windows feature(s)? These options are in Control Panel->Programs & Features->Turn Windows Features on or off->Microsoft .NET Framework 3.x (just realized your examples are .NET 3.5 and not .NET 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what happens and why precisely, 
but **commenting the following line** and not adding metadataBehavior to 
host.Description.Behaviors fixes the prob:

```
  host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
```

I don't really need this feature so it's ok to squeeze it, but I still wonder why this was causing the Exception... (Especially that is is working on my partner's workstation, so I am sure it has to do with *"some setting somewhere"*)

Commenting the exact same kind of line on other projects makes them work too, so there is no doubt left.

Answer (score 2):

This is the message you get when you aren't authorized to create a service host at a given address. In your case you are getting this using the NetTcpBinding. Here are some possible solutions to this - you just need to run through them.

1. Another process is using the same binding - TCP port 8000 (IIS?)
2. You are not running VS.NET as an administrator
3. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) is not installed (windows feature required for net.tcp binding)
4. Windows Communication Foundation HTTP/Non-HTPP Activation is not installed (windows feature under .NET Framework 3.x)
5. Firewall is blocking successful Net.Tcp communication.

Comment: Thank you. 1 \ I am using TCPView / netstat to monitor port usage and Port 8000 is free. When a port is already listened to I get another exception (more explicit). 2 \ I am running VS as admin + I launched release exe file outside VS as admin with same results

Comment: @SilverNinja: changing 127.0.0.1 to my real IP resulted in the following error "The requested address is not valid in its context" and yes metadataBehavior is null

Comment: Do you have Network Activation Services running? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561286/wcf-tcp-binding-the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context-error

Comment: How to see if Network Activation Services are running effectively, whats are the exact names of the considered services ? Anyway, I'm not sure this fixes the problem I had at first round

Comment: Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) is not installed by default with Windows. You must enable the feature. Control Panel->Programs & Features->Turn Windows Features on or off->Windows Process Activation Service. This will add the Net.Pipe Listener Adapter you seek.

Comment: WAS is not installed on my partner's PC and the WCF projects are running fine on his workstation (see edit) so I don't think this is the culprit. I'm still miserably stuck... :(

Comment: I installed WAS, just to make sure. As expected, no effect. More, I still have a CommunicationException "The requested address is not valid in its context" when I put my ip instead of localhost address

Comment: Are there any required windows services that may be not running ?

Comment: Try option #4 above...the possibilities are growing. ;-)

Comment: I had big hopes on 4# :-) Sounded nice. Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. I gotta keep digging :-) this is very critical to us so I'm gonna put whatever time it takes into it.

Comment: @MikaJacobi You should start commenting out property assignments in the above sections to see if certain property values are failing (TransactionFlow, Security, metadataBehavior, etc.).

Comment: @SilverNinja : Thank you for your help and support. I felt less alone during my struggle. You last comment on metadataBehavior has put me on the track so I messed out with the code a bit and found the culprit. (I did not think of twisting the code actually, as the same code is working on my partner's workstation). See my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b67d03d9-e2e6-40e6-aa44-2af6ce5a8a38/
the problem is that the metadata binding is not http and so the firewall is blocking it.

Comment: Thank You. My issue was in fact what I described in my own answer about metadataBehavior. However this could have been something else like what you describe, as the error can be caused by different possible causes

Answer (score -3):

1->Open the SQL Server

2->Right click database and select properties

3->Click options (left panel) change to database collection select Latin1_General_CI_AI

mission complated.