# why i can't use HttpListener in my Windows 10 computer? (System.PlatformNotSupportedException)

Tags: c#, windows

[WCF : PlatformNotSupportedException when running Server Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967674/wcf-platformnotsupportedexception-when-running-server-projects) it doesn't work for me...

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Net.HttpListener.IsSupported); // false
```

Code:

```
HttpListener h = new HttpListener();
```

Error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform

In System.Net.HttpListener..ctor()
```

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 1703,i don't know why it happened.

but i can use it on Windows 10 1511

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF : PlatformNotSupportedException when running Server Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967674/wcf-platformnotsupportedexception-when-running-server-projects)

Comment: no,it can't help me

Answer (score 6):

http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=92534

It helped me!

because my HTTP start option is 4.

i fixed it.

```
sc config http start=demand
sc start http
```

Comment: Wow. How utterly obscure. You'd think this would be fundamental enough of a breaking change in Windows 10 that the exception message would say something meaningful.