# PlatformNotSupportedException error when starting Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator, azure-emulator

I've installed Azure libraries and Azure SDKs for .NET, but I can't start Azure Storage Emulator. It's giving me this error: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.`

I tried to reinstall SDK, netcore, and storage emulator, and I ran these commands as admin. But no luck. Any idea?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe init
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool
Found SQL Instance (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
Creating database AzureStorageEmulatorDb510 on SQL instance '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.

Granting database access to user myuser.
Database access for user myuser was granted.

Initialization successful. The storage emulator is now ready for use.
The storage emulator was successfully initialized and is ready to use.


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool

Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.HttpListener..ctor()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.CheckStoragePrerequisites.CheckPortReservation(Action`1 showErrorMessage)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.CheckStoragePrerequisites.CheckPrerequisites(Action`1 showErrorMessage, Boolean& fixWithInit)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.EmulatorProcessController.EnsureRunning(Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Commands.StartCommand.RunCommand()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899696/why-i-cant-use-httplistener-in-my-windows-10-computer-system-platformnotsuppo

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS you're a life saver! it works!

Comment: :). Let me close this as a duplicate then.