# WCF on Windows Service PlatformNotSupportedException On Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, windows-server

I'm hosting a WCF service in an Windows Service. It works in several versions of Windows, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10, Windows Server 2016...

However, in **Windows Server 2012 R2** it doesn't work.

When I try to start the service I get this error:

```
Service can not be started. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This platform does not support operation.
   at System.Net.HttpListener..ctor()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channe...
```

Here is the service code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace WindowsService
{
    public partial class GerenciadorMorphoService : ServiceBase
    {
        private ServiceHost mHost = null;

        public GerenciadorMorphoService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (mHost != null)
            {
                mHost.Close();
            }

            Uri EndPoint = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndPointHttp"]);
            mHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Terminais.Terminal), EndPoint);

            ServiceMetadataBehavior behave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
            {
                HttpGetEnabled = true
            };

            mHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behave);

            mHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (mHost != null)
            {
                mHost.Close();
                mHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The address in **ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndPointHttp"]** is
**http://localhost:46125/bioacesso/terminais.svc**

The firewall is disabled,
There is no application using the port 46125 (I verified with the netstat command)
I am using the Administrator account.

I saw some posts here like this: [WCF : PlatformNotSupportedException when running Server Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967674/wcf-platformnotsupportedexception-when-running-server-projects),

however, any solution suggested worked for my case,

Anybody knows what can be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in this link

http://www.toughdev.com/content/2017/12/fixing-platformnotsupportedexception-when-running-a-window-communication-foundation-application/

The http driver was disabled, and in the windows 2012 you can only change that in the registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP

The key **Start** has to be 3 (4 is disabled)

Comment: Thank you that was a non trivial answer!